# Angular data-grid(ag-grid-ng2) not supported in one of the IE11(version:11.967.16299.0)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, internet-explorer-11, ag-grid-ng2

There is a problem regarding the data-grid on angular2. Which means, the event emitter is not loading when we use IE version 11.967.16299.0. The issue is only happening in the client machine, so i am not able to explore more anything without logging. The console logging on the program helps to identify the problem which is based on the event emitter.

ag-grid-ng2(version:6.2.0) which is used as the data-grid to load the list view content on my project. The data grid that have 3 event emitters(onRowSelected(), onRowUnSelected() and onDoubleClicked()) declared, which is given on below. And also the grid options and event listening call will be given in below as I did.

I'm sharing the code. But its fails to log the inputs from event emitter onRowSelected() in inbox.component.ts.

```
<----------------datagrid.component.ts-------->

@Component({
    selector: "dt-datagrid",
    template: "<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid id=\"agGrid\"  style=\"height:100%;width:100%\"  class=\"ag-fresh hidepaging\" (cellClicked)=\"cellClicked($event)\" (rowDoubleClicked)=\"doubleClicked($event)\" [gridOptions]=\"gridOptions\"></ag-grid-ng2>",
    providers: [PtRoutingService, MessagesService, ContactsService, LibraryService, CoverSheetService, FormService, AutoreplyService, MessageRoutingService, FilterService, OverlayService, AutoForwardService]

})

export class DataGridComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input("init") dgSource: string = "";
    @Input("keywords") keywords: string = "";
    @Input("firstkeywords") firstkeywords: string = "";
    @Output() onRowSelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Output() onRowUnSelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Output() onDoubleClicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    public gridOptions: any = [];
}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.gridOptions = {
            enableServerSideSorting: true,
            enableServerSideFilter: false,
            columnDefs: columnDefs,
            rowSelection: "multiple",
            enableColResize: true,
            localeText: { noRowsToShow: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open mainRecord" ></span><span class="mainText">This folder is empty</span>' },
            suppressMovableColumns: true,
            rowModelType: "pagination",
            onRowSelected: (event: any): any => this.rowSelected(event),
            context: {
                libService: this.libraryService
            },
        };
}

private rowSelected(event: any): void {
        if (event.node.selected) {
            console.log((new Date) + " : DataGrid row selected - rowSelected() - datagridcomponent.ts");
            console.log("Selected node value - rowSelected() - datagridcomponent.ts:");
            console.log(event);
            this.onRowSelected.emit(event.node.data);
        } else {
            console.log((new Date) + " : DataGrid row unselected - rowSelected() - datagridcomponent.ts");
            console.log("Unselected node value - rowSelected() - datagridcomponent.ts:");
            console.log(event);
            this.onRowUnSelected.emit(event.node.data);
        }
    }







<----------------Inbox.component.ts-------->

public onRowSelected(event: any): void {
        console.log((new Date) + ": Start onRowSelected() - InboxComponent");
        console.log((new Date) + ": Argument Event value  - onRowSelected()- InboxComponent");
        console.log(event);
}






<-----------------package.json------------------->

{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "coffee-script": "1.11.1",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-combine-js": "^0.1.14",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "1.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-ts": "6.0.0-beta.17",
    "moment": "2.15.0",
    "polyfills": "^2.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.1",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "ag-grid": "6.2.1",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "6.2.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "1.2.5",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap.native": "1.0.5",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.1.10",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "0.0.12",
    "pdfjs-dist": "1.6.221",
    "polyfills": "^2.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contain some error message? can you post the Enough code (include the html file and related service) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no issue found when I check with the developer tool.